Web Jobs deployment problem even pipeline is successful
I was deploying a web jobs using azure pipelines , my azure infrastructure is also build using terraform .
Initially when the pipeline is running successfully ,the web jobs are successfully deployed
but I deleted the deployed web job manually from the azure portal
From then when I was trying to deploy it , the web job is not at all deployed in the portal
Even through the pipeline which is successfully running and I tried manually adding the web job
It fails in both the ways
It is a .NET application
I want to publish using azure pipelines and automated the infrastructure using terraform
I tried by creating the new web app service to deploy the web job
But still it is not working

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
